# Enqueue Script with URL parameters

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, query-variable

I have the following I'm trying to enqueue in `functions.php`

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'param-example', 'https://domain.com/example?f=j&s=w&c=t', array(), null );
```

Except WordPress is escaping the ampersands in the HTML which is breaking the script.

How can I prevent WordPress from escaping the URL in `wp_enqueue_script`?

The other examples that seem close to this question haven't worked.

Comment: Are you sure that's what is breaking your script? I have an ampersand in mine and it's working fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate how is breaking the script when it's escaped?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress can automatically add the query variables for you. Instead of directly writing the query arguments, you can use it this way:

```
$args = array(
        'f' => 'j',
        's' => 'w',
        'c' => 't'
    );
wp_enqueue_script( 'param-example', add_query_arg( $args, 'https://domain.com/example') );
```

This is your solution, since according to [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/), the return value is unescaped by default.

Comment: This isn't what's needed. The variables don't need to be unescaped, the ampersands between the variables need to be. This doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a hook to target specific URLS.

e.g.

```
// 
// Add to functions.php, or to a Plugin file.
//
// Change, CHANGE_ME.com to Urls you want to stop wordpress from converting.
//
add_filter('clean_url', 'hook_strip_ampersand', 99, 3);
function hook_strip_ampersand($url, $original_url, $_context) {
    if (strstr($url, "CHANGE_ME.com") !== false) {
        $url = str_replace("&#038;", "&", $url);
    }

    return $url;
}
```

For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504142/loading-google-maps-api-with-wp-enqueue-script/9504653

Comment: How do you then enqueue the script? wp_enqueue_script( 'param-example', $url ); doesn't seem to do it.